# sound and flame sensor

Tags: raspbian, gpio, sensor

```
SOUND_PIN = 4
FLAME = 2
LED = 26
LED2 = 18
PIR = 6

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
import os
import picamera


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(PIR,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(SOUND_PIN,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(FLAME,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(LED,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LED2,GPIO.OUT)

count = 0
state = 0

def SSENSOR(PIR):
    time.sleep(1)
    if GPIO.input(PIR):
        GPIO.output(LED,True)
        print "pir"
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(LED,False)

        nowtime = datetime.datetime.now()
        print nowtime

        camera.capture(str(nowtime) + '.jpg')

    else:
        GPIO.output(LED,False)

def DETECTED(SOUND_PIN):
    time.sleep(1)
    if GPIO.input(SOUND_PIN):

        print "sound detected"

    else:
        GPIO.output(LED,False)



def FIRE(FLAME):
    time.sleep(1)
    if GPIO.input(FLAME):
        print "fire"
        GPIO.output(LED2,True)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(LED2,False)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(LED2,True)
        time.sleep(1)
while True:
    DETECTED(SOUND_PIN)
    FIRE(FLAME)
    SSENSOR(PIR)
```

This is part of my code. It works. But I don't do anything, it print "sound detected", "fire" repeatedly. Is it code problem or sensor problem? (I want to detect flame and sound)

re))))) It's my all code. SSENSOR(Motion Sensor) works very well, so I remove it on photo.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the code.  However we can't say if the code is wrong as the snippet is incomplete.  We also need to see your wiring.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's all codes about sound and frame sensor. I connect sound sensor(do = GPIO4, + = 3v, gnd = GND), frame sensor(do = GPIO25, + =3v, gnd = GND). When I disconnect sound sensor, "sound detected" do not appear. Is it sensor problem?

Comment: We need to see the full code and a photo of the wiring.

Comment: It's my full code and photo.

Comment: In your particular case a good approach is to decouple the debugging of software and hardware. I.e. write a very, very simple script (it's probably a three-liner) to repeatedly poll the input pin and print its state. Now play with the respective sensor and watch what happens. If you're sure the sensor behaves the way intended proceed with your original script.

Comment: The sensitivity of each of those sensors is controlled by the rectangular blue pots by turning the screwdriver slot.  They can have multiple turns.  Have you tried moving between the extremes?

Comment: Also GPIO 2 (and 3) is not a good choice as it has a strongish pull-up to 3V3 on board.  Try a different GPIO.